# Broken h1 link doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

The `<h1>` link is supposed to link to `#Section1`. I can't figure out where along the lines this action broke. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://codepen.io/fjenpen/pen/pROPov

```
<div class="nav">
<ul id="menu" style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li><a href="#Section1" style="text-decoration:none"><h1>Our Brands</h1>   </a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="main">
<div id="Section1" class="content">

  <p>View our brands</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You missed the `#` i.e. `href="#Section1`

Comment: @ Satpal this fixed the error page, however h1 still does not link the #section1...any ideas?

Comment: It looks like it is working to me

Comment: If you click on link within #flexiselDemo3 and then click on Our brands it does not link to #section1

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you already placed

```
<div id="#Section1" class="content">
```

I guess there is still a non-sense thing:

The `<a href="#Section1" style="text-decoration:none">` is an `<a>`, so how is it supposed to link to any div? (`<div id="Section1" class="content">`)

The only thing you're doing by writing the `<div id="Section1" class="content">`
is creating a div. You're not linking anything to anywhere.

If I'm wrong, please tell me, because I'm also some kind of newbie in this, but I'm almost sure you're not linking anything to anywhere. You're just creating a `<div>`, and a `<a>` inside a `<li>`

Comment: You can use `href="#Section1"` to link to an element with an ID of `Section1`

Comment: Thanks Kodos Johnson. There's a thing I didn't know.